# ajax / php commenting system not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo, comments

I have this commenting system which doesn't work well. It inserts the comment into the database, but only shows it after refreshing the page. I want it to show immediately after clicking submit button, and display with a sliding effect.

I'm suspecting the `$arr[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($v);` is causing the problem. I'm using PDO now, so I know that must not be there, but when I remove it to code stops working.

My code is below.

```
<?php
    class Comment{
        private $data = array();
        public function __construct($row){
            $this->data = $row;
        }
        public function markup(){
            $d = &$this->data;
            $link_open = '';
            $link_close = '';
            if($d['url']){
                $link_open = '<a href="'.$d['url'].'">';
                $link_close =  '</a>';
            }
            $d['dt'] = strtotime($d['dt']);
            $url = 'http://'.dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
            return '
            <div class="comment">
                <div class="name">'.$link_open.$d['name'].$link_close.'</div>
                <div class="date" title="Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.date('d M Y',$d['dt']).'</div>
                <p>'.$d['body'].'</p>
            </div>
            ';
         }
         public static function validate(&$arr){
             $errors = array();
             $data  = array();
             if(!($data['email'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))){
                 $errors['email'] = '<div>Please insert your email</div>';
             }
             if(!($data['url'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'url',FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))){  
                 $url = '';
             }
             if(!($data['body'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'body',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text')))){
                 $errors['body'] = '<div>Please type your comment</div>';
             }
             if(!($data['name'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text')))){
                 $errors['name'] = '<div>Please insert your name</div>';
             }
             if(!empty($errors)){   
                 $arr = $errors;
                 return false;
             }
             foreach($data as $k=>$v){
                 $arr[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
             }
             $arr['email'] = strtolower(trim($arr['email']));
             return true;   
         }
         private static function validate_text($str){
             if(mb_strlen($str,'utf8')<1)
                 return false;
                 $str = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($str));
                 $str = str_replace(array(chr(10),chr(13)),'',$str);    
                 return $str;
         }
     }
 ?>
```

And also my js file:

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var working = false;
        $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(working) return false;
                working = true;
                $('#submit').val('working');
                $('span.error').remove();
            $.post('commenting/submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
            working = false;
            $('#submit').val('submit');
            if(msg.status){
        $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
                $('#body').val('');
            }else {
                $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
                    $('label[for='+k+']').append('<span class="error">'+v+'</span>');
                    });
                }
            },'json');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For the system to behave like you want it to, you need to use AJAX and I don't see you using it.

Comment: Thx for that, although I am not much experienced in Javascript etc, I know it was working like that without ajax, I changed the whole system to PDO and all hell broke loose then, any suggestions?

Comment: I improved formatting and removed the "please" and "thank you" statements to conform with community standards.

Comment: @JasonMc92, thx for that man

Answer (score 0):

Whats the upper tag for:

```
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="name">'.$link_open.$d['name'].$link_close.'</div>
        <div class="date" title="Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.date('d M Y',$d['dt']).'</div>
        <p>'.$d['body'].'</p>
    </div>
```

If you show your comments inside the commets tag, for example:

```
<div id="comments">
<div class="comment">
    <div class="name">'.$link_open.$d['name'].$link_close.'</div>
    <div class="date" title="Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.date('d M Y',$d['dt']).'</div>
    <p>'.$d['body'].'</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Then edit your js as below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var working = false;
        $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(working) return false;
            working = true;
            $('#submit').val('working');
            $('span.error').remove();
            $.post('commenting/submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
                working = false;
                $('#submit').val('submit');
                if(msg.status){
                    $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
                    $('.comment').val('');
                    /// I added below code to show updated comments inside of comments tag
                    $('#comments').html(msg.html+$('#comments').html());

                }else {
                    $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
                        $('label[for='+k+']').append('<span class="error">'+v+'</span>');
                    });
                }
            },'json');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thx for the effort but it didnt fix it, I am still thinking the problem is the freaking  **mysql_real_escape_string($v);**, any suggestions for that?

Comment: @Jman Dont use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you using PDO. There is no way to sql injetion on PDO. So you dont need to use `mysql_real_escape_string`. But i think problem is not that.

Comment: Can you change this line `$('#comments').html(msg.html+$('#comments').html());` with this `console.log(msg.html);` and check your JS console, see whats prints.

Comment: Yeah I know that but if I remove  foreach($data as $k=>$v){$arr[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($v);} the code fails completely and no database inserting happens.
I will now try the console.log

Comment: Can you try this one: `console.log(msg);`

Comment: I finally took the code and built it again from scratch by my own knowledge, some further questions if oyu are interested:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550757/insert-values-and-display-the-result-on-the-same-page-ajax